# How do I show/activate the text cursor in open document? [C#, EnvDTE]

Tags: c#, envdte

I'm trying to set the cursor in an open document, but it doesn't show. I can see that the line is "marked" and I can "navigate" the lines, but the cursor is not shown, and thus I'm not able to write anything. Also it seems like the document doesn't really fully load, since guidelines and the navigationmap is not shown either.
*Which makes me believe that the focus isn't being set completely inside the document.* 
I have confirmed that the focus indeed is not set in the document in the window, since If I have the output window focused before, it's still focused after the `window.Activate()` method has been called.

I've used the common way of opening the document through `ProjectItem.Open(Constants.vsViewKindCode)`, activating it, and using the `TextSelection.GotoLine(1,false)` method.

This correctly shows the document and sets the line correctly, but I have to manually click inside the document for the cursor to appear.

The code I have:

```
Window window = projItem.Open(Constants.vsViewKindCode);
window.Activate(); <----- this does not focus the window.
TextSelection textSelection = window.Document.Selection as TextSelection;
textSelection.GotoLine(1, false);
```

I want to not have to manually click inside the document for it to load completely and for me to be able to write in it.

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well, another issue I had to solve by myself... Two for two. I guess people don't know that much in here like I'd hoped. Oh well.

Anywho, I discovered that if you use `DTE.ItemOperations.OpenFile(path);` and nothing else,
the file will receive focus correctly, just like it should have when you use `.Activate()`.